# How to extract required groups using C# Regular Expression pattern

Tags: c#, regex, regex-greedy

I am learning regular expression. I am trying to use the following regex

```
^(?<type>\W?\w+)(?<middle>\s\w+)?\s(((?<seconds>\d+)[s-]?)?)\s?(?<body>.+?)$
```

and the example string i am trying to match is

**IDCH test tes 15s Discover Spring Love what you find Quelle chance ! Fevr16**

I want the following output:

type: IDCH

middle: test tes

seconds: 15s

body: Discover.....

I am not getting the expected output using my above pattern. Can anyone help what is wrong with my regex pattern?

Here is what i am getting currently:
type: IDCH

middle: test

seconds:

body: tes 15s ........

Thanks

Comment: Should `middle` match multiple words separated by spaces?

Comment: yes please. it can be zero or more occurrences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse your very specific input string this did the job for me:

```
^(?<type>\W?\w+)(?<middle>(\s\D+)*)?\s(?<seconds>\d+s)?\s?(?<body>.+?)$
```

The middle part catches any litteral except numbers when you use `\D`

```
(?<middle>(\s\D+)*)?
```

That give seconds the chance to match the number with \d+

```
(?<seconds>\d+s)?
```

**EDIT:**

to extract the seconds you should look for a number preceded by a space and directly followed by an `s`

```
^(?<type>\W*\w*)(?<middle>(\s\w+)*)(?<seconds>\s\d+s)\s(?<body>.+?)$
```

Comment: @MaciejLos But not working for IDCH test tes2 15s Discover Spring Love what you find Quelle chance ! Fevr16

Comment: @MaciejLos , I basically trying to extract the seconds bit using the groups

Comment: @MukilDeepthi the thing is that there are many string for which this will not work. It always depends on the degrees of freedom that your input string has. this should guide your quest for the fitting regular expression.

Comment: I edited my post to incorporate your comment. If you change the string again we could go on forever :) cheers